# Pass tag Key and Value for resource name in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have my cloudformation json template which has the resource(VPC to be specific) Tags mapped something like this:

`"Tags" : [ {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "nameofresource"} ]` 
Now I am running this from a shell script with the command

`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name stackname --template-body file://template.json`

I want to pass the name from the parameter. I tried it using

`--parameters ParameterKey=Name,ParameterValue=somevalue`

after my template. But it throws an error. Also I tried replacing the `"Value"` in the JSON with `"Ref" : "paramkeyvalue"` and passed it as required from the cli.
How do I pass the name from parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Command:**

```
  aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name "MyVPC" --template-body file://test.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=Name,ParameterValue="MyVPC"
```

**test.yaml**

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "Name": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "MyName"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "myVPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                "EnableDnsSupport": "false",
                "EnableDnsHostnames": "false",
                "InstanceTenancy": "default",
                "Tags": [{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "Name"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. Throws an error `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies in the Resources block of the template`

Comment: Did you define the parameters? I added the exact code for you in the answer. Please check

Comment: I was missing the parameters in the template. Had tried it earlier but there was some mismatch with the parameters in the command. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the parameters Key and value name as ParameterKey and ParameterValue

--parameters ParameterKey=Name,ParameterValue=somevalue

"Tags" : [ {"ParameterKey" : "Name", "ParameterValue" : "somevalue"} ]

Comment: What if there are multiple tags? Like I want to tag my VPC and also my Gateway. How will i pass both those parameters as "name"? Also when I run this, it gives me the error `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them.`

Comment: ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=MyKey ParameterKey=InstanceType,ParameterValue=t1.micro. You can add one more paramter type by providing spaces. You will also pass parameters as json type. Can you paste your parameter section from your template?